Exclude entire blocks from computation in Dask/Xarray
I am processing a large dataset of non-rectangular satellite imagery with xarray/dask. I know in advance from the footprint of the imagery, that large parts of the xarray are no-data (since the image does not have a rectangular shape as xarray requires). That means I end up with an xarray that has a lot of chunks where I know that they are all NaN but xarray doesn't know. Is there a way to exclude these chunks from computation?

Here a pseudo-code example to illustrate:
import xarray as xr

da = xr.open_zarr('src/path', decode_coords='all')
print(da)
# <xarray.DataArray 'band_data' (y: 28981, x: 41721)>
# dask.array<getitem, shape=(28981, 41721), dtype=float32, chunksize=(2048, 2048),
# chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
# Coordinates:
#     spatial_ref  int64 ...
#   * x            (x) float64 7.18e+05 7.18e+05 7.18e+05 ... 8.432e+05 8.432e+05
#   * y            (y) float64 9.736e+06 9.736e+06 ... 9.823e+06 9.823e+06

# this loads and computes each chunk, also the ones where I know in advance that they're all NaN
# ideally the all NaN chunks would not be loaded/computed
result = computationally_expensive_func(da)
...
result.compute()


What are you trying to reduce here? Computation time? Does computationally_expensive_func know how to handle chunks? If so, a short-circuit inside computationally_expensive_func would work OK.

Yes, I thought about that and added a short-circuit as an answer. Wondering if there's a simpler solution tho

What I came up with now is the function below. It returns the min_x and min_y location of each chunk outside the footprint. I can then pass these to a function I apply in xarray.map_blocks, where I can check if the block is one of the empty ones:
def get_empty_chunks(ds:xr.Dataset, aoi:Union[Polygon, MultiPolygon]) -> List[Tuple[int, int]]:
    '''
    Gets the first xy index of each empty chunk

    The function creates a grid corresponding to the chunks of the dataset and checks if the chunk is empty by intersecting it with the footprints.
    For empty chunks, it returns the first xy index.

    Args:
        ds: chunked xarray dataset
        aoi: area of interest as shapely polygon

    Returns:
        list: list of tuples with the first xy index of each empty chunk
    '''
    # create grid
    x = np.cumsum([0] + list(ds.chunks['x']))
    y = np.cumsum([0] + list(ds.chunks['y']))

    x[-1] = x[-1] -1
    y[-1] = y[-1] -1

    x = ds.x.isel(x=x).values
    y = ds.y.isel(y=y).values

    hlines = [((x1, yi), (x2, yi)) for x1, x2 in zip(x[:-1], x[1:]) for yi in y]
    vlines = [((xi, y1), (xi, y2)) for y1, y2 in zip(y[:-1], y[1:]) for xi in x]

    grids = list(polygonize(MultiLineString(hlines + vlines)))

    grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=grids, crs=ds.rio.crs)

    grid = grid[~grid.intersects(aoi)]

    # get xmin, ymin for all grid cells
    empty_chunks = []
    for i, row in grid.iterrows():
        x, y = row.geometry.bounds[:2]
        empty_chunks.append((x, y))

    return empty_chunks

def computationally_expensive_func(ds_block, empty_chunks):
    # skipping empty chunks
    if len(empty_chunks) > 0:

        if (ds_block.x[0], ds_block.y[0]) in empty_chunks:
            return ds_block

    # do other stuff with the non-empty blocks here and return  
    
ds = xr.open_zarr('src/path', decode_coords='all')
aoi = gpd.read_file('path/to/aoi').geometry
ds = ds.map_blocks(computationally_expensive_func, [get_empty_chunks(ds, aoi)], template=ds)

It feels kinda hacky tho, hoping there's a simpler solution
